# Method pointer with boost::bind and map

Tags: c++, boost, bind

Is there a nicer way of doing this

```
auto commodityOneLeg = boost::bind(&VegaFactory::load_commodity_one_leg,this,conn,_1);
std::map<std::string,decltype(commodityOneLeg)> methods;
methods.insert(std::make_pair("COMMODITYONELEG",commodityOneLeg));
methods.insert(std::make_pair("FXOPTION",boost::bind(&VegaFactory::load_fx_index,this,conn,_1)));
methods.insert(std::make_pair("FXBARROPT",boost::bind(&VegaFactory::load_fx_bar_opt,this,conn,_1)));

methods.insert(std::make_pair("COMMODITYINDEX",boost::bind(&VegaFactory::load_fx_index,this,conn,_1)));
auto f = methods.find(trade_table);

if(f != methods.end()) {
    fx_opt = (f->second)(t_id);
}
```

Is there a way of declaring the type of std:map<> without having to declare a mapping first on the previous line? I guess I mean aesthetically - Code should look neat right?

Is there a cleaner/simpler way to do this c++ string switch statement overall when the input is a 'trade type' string.

**Edit**

To clarify further. I can manually write out the type of the boost:bind type but that seems excessive. And this is probably a really good example of where auto and decltype can be used to simplify the code.
However having to declare one entry in the map one way and the others in a different way just looks wrong; so that's what I want to address

Comment: Maybe you could use boost signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO using [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html) is a more clear way. There is also the [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals.html) library but it is [deprecated](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html) starting from Boost 1.54. The following code demonstrates it. I think something similar is possible to implement using the [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html) library too.

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef boost::signals2::signal<bool (int)> CSignal;
typedef CSignal::slot_type CSignalSlotType;
typedef std::map<std::string, CSignalSlotType> CMethodMap;

bool Func1(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}

bool Func2(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    CMethodMap methods;
    methods.insert(std::make_pair("Func1", boost::bind(&Func1, 1, _1)));
    methods.insert(std::make_pair("Func2", boost::bind(&Func2, 2, _1)));

    auto it = methods.find("Func1");
    if(it != methods.end()) {
        CSignal signal;
        signal.connect(it->second);
        auto rt = signal(2);
        if (rt) {
            const bool result = *rt;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample code using the [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html). It looks even simpler but I used to use the Signals2 library.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef boost::function<bool (int)> CFunction;
typedef std::map<std::string, CFunction> CMethodMap;

bool Func1(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}

bool Func2(int a, int b) {
    return a < b;
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    CMethodMap methods;
    methods.insert(std::make_pair("Func1", boost::bind(&Func1, 1, _1)));
    methods.insert(std::make_pair("Func2", boost::bind(&Func2, 2, _1)));

    auto it = methods.find("Func1");
    if(it != methods.end()) {
        auto &f = it->second;
        const bool result = f(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now thats clean. I'll have a browse through Signals2 as I didn't know about that